# Disable caching for PHP Server variables in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to use the data from the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` php variable for some custom functionality in Magento.

However, I'm not sure if this variable is cached because it seems to act like a constant.

I'm using Chrome, and when I use two different tabs, one with mobile emulation, and one without, I see the same user agent string. When I do the same thing on a test script on my local PHP, it shows me the user agent string for the specific tab i.e. mobile user agent string on mobile emulator, and a desktop one otherwise.

I also tried this using two different browsers (Chrome and Firefox) and after a cache refresh, I opened Chrome using the iPhone emulator and see a iPhone user agent string, but when I open Firefox I see the same iPhone user agent string.

I'm not sure what's going on but I'm not enjoying this. Is there a way to disable caching permanently for PHP $_SERVER variables in Magento? Or is there some foolproof way of getting a non-cached user agent string? I've tried `getenv` but it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, PHP won't cache the values in `$_SERVER`.  It's far more likely your production Magento system is using some sort of output/full-page-caching that doesn't take user agent strings into account.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Is it safe to disable full page caching permanently? Or could there be a way to bypass the full page cache? I'm using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` on the 1column.phtml and 3columns.phtml

Comment: @ObinwanneHill Depends entirely on your cache strategy and your traffic levels. Also, I'd confirm that what I pulled out of thin air is the actual problem :)

Comment: Ok. Based on what I've tried, it looks like full page caching could be the issue. When you clear the Full Page Cache, the $_SERVER variable in question resets and then is set when you reload the page, and stays that way until you clear the cache again. Will see if I can find a way to disable it in the page.xml or layout.xml. I stumbled on this [(Disable cache for specific template)](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44008/disable-cache-for-specific-template) and will try the answer to see if it could work

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem of setting cache expire without defining if it's public or private, but solved it by turning cache-control to `private`.

```
header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate");
```

with this, PHP will use more memory and CPU because because it's not using shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2 FPC is biggest problem. It will caching $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] variables too. i also faced this issue when i am giving support to mobile app developers.

To fix this issue, try the foll

```
protected $httpHeader;


public function __construct(
   ...
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header $httpHeader
   ...
) {
    $this->httpHeader = $httpHeader;
}

public function getUserAgent(){
  return $this->httpHeader->getHttpUserAgent();        
}
```

this file Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header returns clean value of user agent. so no caching problem.